# Issue signing up new users in Django

Tags: python, django, django-users

I have the following signup flow in an app using Django 1.11-

accounts/views.py:

```
from .forms import UserForm

def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

accounts/forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password']
```

It does appear to "register" a new user, in that it creates a new user in the database. The issue is I cannot login with that newly created user, the username/pw combo does not match. Going into the database I see the newly created users, but the password is in plain text: "password". But the first user I created through the command line, `python manage.py createsuperuser` has a salted hash as the password like `pasdfhjasf8234jk324hgsdfa8df89asdf987` and I can login correctly using the password I made for it, ie "password".

How do I save new users using my ModelForm where Django knows to correctly store the password as a salted hash?

Comment: You probably want to use - or extend - the built-in [UserCreationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm), which takes care of this and additionally provides a "confirm password" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *not* set the password through the boilerplate code in the `ModelForm`, you need to use [**`.set_password(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password) to hash the password:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Django however has already a [**`UserCreationForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) that implements this. It will use two form fields to validate that the user has entered the same password twice. We can thus subclass the `UserCreationForm`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email']
```

Comment: I used the usercreationform at first, but it did not implement email. I followed this: https://wsvincent.com/django-user-authentication-tutorial-signup/

Comment: @codyc4321: you can add the `'username'` and/or `'email'` to the `fields`. You thus can *subclass* the `UserCreationForm`.